# Null is not being selected in the select list SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

There is a table with structure shown below. The table contains `NULL` values

[image]

The queries being used to select the `NULL`

Query #1

```
select * from table where items1 = 'NULL'
```

Query #2

```
Select * from table where items2 like '%NULL%'
```

but, neither of the queries is returning any rows!

Comment: It seems you have some answers to your question. I would highly recommend you do some reading and research on normalization. What are you going to do when you need ITEMS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to compare a value to `NULL`, like this:

```
select * from table where items1 IS NULL
```

You can change a little bit the behaviour, but it's not recommended. For more ifnormation see [SET ANSI_NULLS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188048.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can't Do What You tried without Setting `SET ANSI_NULLS  OFF`. Because `NULL` is Different Things in ANY Databases. Anything with `NULL` Becomes `NULL`

eg.

```
 select NULL + 1  -- OUTPUT : NULL
 select NULL + 'test'  -- OUTPUT : NULL
```

Even NULL Return False

eg.

```
select case when NULL=1 then 0 else 1 end  --   return false hence 1

select case when NULL=0 then 1 else 0 end  --   return false hence 0
```

try this :

```
select * from table where items1 is NULL
```

or

EDIT:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS  OFF

select * from table where items1=null
```

Comment: That's not exact: if you SET `ANSI_NULLS` to `OFF` your answer becomes plain wrong.